# Каковы принципиальные различия между child_process и worker_threads?

Tags: node.js, многопоточность, процесс, multiprocessing

Вот сейчас подумываю над тем, чтобы вынести тяжелое вычисление в отдельный процесс. Изначально ориентировался на child_process, однако недавно узнал, что есть еще такая тема как worker_threads. Но в чем разница между ними, не понял - вроде как оба запускают отдельный процесс а потом асинхронно возвращают результат.

Так какая же принципиальная разница межу ними и в каких случаях что из этого нужно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первые строки документации (выделение моё):

> Workers are **useful for performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations**; do not use them for I/O, since Node.js’s built-in mechanisms for performing operations asynchronously already treat it more efficiently than Worker threads can.
>
> Workers, unlike child processes or when using the `cluster` module, can also **share memory efficiently** by transferring `ArrayBuffer` instances or sharing `SharedArrayBuffer` instances between them.

Т.е. как раз то, что вам надо, судя по вашему описанию задачи. Только надо понимать, что они ещё в очень ранней альфе и вообще за флагом, так что я бы не стал сейчас писать на них продакшн код.